# Postgresql: How to sum the ASCII codes of characters in a column?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Example setup:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl (word TEXT);
INSERT INTO tbl VALUES ('abc');
INSERT INTO tbl VALUES ('def');
```

How can one write a query that returns the sum of ASCII codes of the characters in each row's `word`?

For example, first row should be `294` ('abc' becomes 97+98+99=294) and second row should be `303` ('def' becomes 100+101+102=303).

Answer (score 4):

The following seems to work:

```
select
    word,
    (select sum(ascii(regexp_split_to_table)) from regexp_split_to_table(word, ''))
from tbl;
```